# Eclipse Juno Menu Item missing

Tags: eclipse-juno

I have a really weird problem: I cant find the configure item in the popupmenu, if i press in eclipse the right mouse button on a project.
All tuts say that, to make a eclipse project into a mvn project, you have to do so (right mouse button on the existing project and than Configure)

Edit: I have installed the m2e plugin from the marketplace.. unfortunately, there is no -> convert to maven project menu item.. I don't know what to do..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded it to Eclipse Indigo. Everything is fine now. The menu Item is where it should be.